# PHP - Encoded Script

Tags: php, encode, trojan

I am working on a Magento Project, version 1.9, which uses an extension called "Magenotification", while downloading the code to my local, my antivrus detected some files as "virus", my antivirus detected: PHP:Agent-RD [Trj]

Three files detected are located under Helper folder, here is the link to the repo:

https://github.com/nahidacm/magetheme/tree/master/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper

I have some questions:

1. How can I decode this file?
2. How can I detect if it actually contains a Trojan or if it was a false positive?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I suggest you raise it as an issue with the repository maintainer. I had a quick attempt at decoding one of the files and for the most part, it looks like a heavily obfuscated licensing check

Comment: I just used https://www.unphp.net/ and I can see the code, it seems fine. why would antivirus detect it as Trojan?

Comment: @Eduardo It's obfuscated code. Rather than trying to decode it and guess if it's malicious, the antivirus is just going to assume it is malicious.

Comment: @ub3rst4r Probably you are right

Comment: @Eduardo When someone finds a suspicious looking package, should they just open it to see what's in it or assume it's a bomb and treat it as such?

Comment: @ub3rst4r It is a good point. Since this site I am working has been running for some years I have to give some explanations if I want to decide it is a "99% bomb" and we need to change extension ;)